# Elasticsearch inconsistent file size and index size query

Tags: elasticsearch

The goal in my application is to measure the total amount of space that elasticsearch is using on the operating system.
The showing of these statistiscs is a functionality that provides users of our application to measure how many disk space they need to run elasticsearch.

Following lucene call is used to get this data.

```
GET _stats/store
```

This returns all indices with their corresponding size_in_bytes property.
The problem is that this number is different than the disk size. The disk size is +- 10 times more than I get returned by this statistics query.
This makes the result of the query not really relevant to what we want to show to the customer.

Is there a more accurate way to get the size that elasticsearch indices are using on the file system?

Comment: Can you provide some numbers?